# MITEL MiVoice Business - SQL Tables for IVR Stats reporting

Tags: sql-server

We have **MITEL MiVoice Business**  as our office phone system and we have default reports that come with it. I have access to the Mitel SQL database and have created a few custom reports from that database using SQL Server. Currently, I have been tasked with creating a report to show the IVR Statistics but I can't seem to find any table that has specific fields relating to the IVR information.

Does anyone know which tables in the Mitel Database can be used to pull up the IVR stats?

I'm looking to create a report which gives data like the number of times the system hung up, the user hung up, number of times they were transferred to the agent, any payments made through the IVR system, etc.

Comment: Mitel has a number of products. You'll need to be more specific about what Mitel product you have.

Comment: Just edited my question and added the name of the product we use.

Comment: Good info. Version information might help you, too, but unfortunately that's not a part of their lineup I personally know much about :/